# How to order rows alpabetically in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following query in mysql:

```
SELECT DISTINCT re1.name as name1, re2.name as name2
FROM Rating ra1 JOIN Reviewer re1
ON re1.rID = ra1.rID
CROSS JOIN
Reviewer re2 JOIN Rating ra2 ON re2.rID = ra2.rID
WHERE ra1.mID = ra2.mID
AND re1.rID != re2.rID
AND re1.rID > re2.rID
ORDER BY name1, name2;
```

This is the retrieved data:

[image]

How can I order the obtained rows alphabetically? (ie, in second row, to switch Brittany and Chris Position)

Thanks

Comment: That's not ordering the rows, that's ordering the columns.

Comment: You don't need `AND re1.rID != re2.rID`. If `re1.rID` is greater than `re2.rID`, they can't be equal.

Comment: What should happen with the duplicate `Chris Jackson` in the name2 column ? Is that desired output ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the functions [`LEAST()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_least) and [`GREATEST()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_greatest):

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
       LEAST(re1.name, re2.name) AS name1, 
       GREATEST(re1.name, re2.name) AS name2
FROM ...
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked! is there a way to do this in an sqlite environment? without LEAST/GREATEST

Comment: @goldenfish instead of LEAST() and GREATEST() use MIN() and MAX() scalar functions.