# How to properly MIN and MAX in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, max, min

I have the following query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 

MIN(re1.name, re2.name) AS name1, 
       MAX(re1.name, re2.name) AS name2


FROM Rating ra1 JOIN Reviewer re1
ON re1.rID = ra1.rID
CROSS JOIN
Reviewer re2 JOIN Rating ra2 ON re2.rID = ra2.rID
WHERE ra1.mID = ra2.mID
AND re1.rID != re2.rID
AND re1.rID > re2.rID
ORDER BY name1, name2;
```

When I run the query in a learning platform I'm currently using (that uses sqlite), it computes a list of coupled names order alphabetically.

[image: list_of_names]

However, if I run the same query in vscode using mysql Ver 8.0.26 for Linux on x86_64
I got the following error:

*You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ', re2.name) AS name1, MAX(re1.name, re2.name) AS name2 FROM Rating ra1' at line 3*

Is MIN MAX in mysql used differently? How do I run the same query using mysql?

Thanks

Comment: `MIN()` and `MAX()` aggregate rows, not columns. Therefore, they accept a single parameter.

Comment: 2) The error message is correct.

Comment: 3) What are you trying to do?!? A [mcve] would help.

Comment: I guess the main question is why, this same query, runs in sqlite and fetch the shown list and why it gets an error in mysql

Comment: @goldenfish: The same question could apply to a `2CV` and a `Mercedes 500 sel coupe`. Both a re cars, but DIFFERENT cars. Also MySQL and SQLite are DIFFERENT databases.

Comment: If you need to know the difference, please do some investigations, after you marked an answer in your previous question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69471409/724039)

Comment: Thank you, Im on it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`MAX()` is for checking in the *same column*, aggregated across multiple rows. I think you want the [`GREATEST()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_greatest) function.

Comment: And `LEAST()` instead of `MIN()`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, indeed, using `least` and `greatest` work fine, but is there a way to run the query shown above (that work in sqlite) in mysql?

Comment: Thanks again, I think I understand now, in sqlite is possible to use more than one variable in `MIN` and `MAX` aggregator but in mysql `MIN` `MAX` only accept one variable at a time because, as you mentioned, they check per column instead of a set of values, correct?

Comment: Yes. MySql is (for once) following the standard in this area, Sqlite is not. This is common in the SQL language: each database platform has its own dialect that is mostly-compatible with the others, and moving between databases will always require some translations between dialects.

Comment: I see, my overall confusion arose due to an actual sqlite-based course that I'm taking. Better to know that these syntactic differences are critical from the beginning, cheers